# How to replace the list value of a key in yaml file from another file?

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I have a file `config.yaml` that looks like this:

```
myenv1:
  abc: efg
  host: ( ENV["HOST1"] )
  db: ( ENV["DB1"] )  
  user: <%= ENV["USER1"] %>
  pass: <%= ENV["VE_PASS1"] %>
  time: 00

myenv2:
  abc: efg
  host: ( ENV["HOST2"] )
  db: ( ENV["DB2"] )  
  user: <%= ENV["USER2"] %>
  pass: <%= ENV["VE_PASS2"] %>
  time: 800
```

And another file `values.yaml` that looks like this:

```
secrets: 
  - MY_PASS_1
  - MY_PASS_2
abc:
  - pqr
psp:
  - jdfhs
```

I need to update/replace the value (it is a list) of a particular key `secret` in the file `values.yaml` with a list of words like `VE_PASS1` and `VE_PASS2` present in the file `config.yaml`.

After running the commands, the `values.yaml` should look like this:

```
secrets: 
  - VE_PASS1
  - VE_PASS2
abc:
  - pqr
psp:
  - jdfhs
```

What would be the Linux command or script to do that?

Comment: Can you please provide the expected result, i.e. content of the modified `config.yaml`, based on these sample input files.

Comment: What is the logical connection between the secrets and the config items? Is it simply based on their index position?

Comment: @pmf edited the question with expected output. Also added an answer. There could be better ways of doing the same

Answer (score 1):

yq can take a list/array of elements as input and can replace the value
of key("secrets" in your case) by the input list.

Example:

> values.yml

```
secrets: 
  - MY_PASS_1
  - MY_PASS_2
abc:
  - pqr
psp:
  - jdfhs
```

#`yq -i ".secrets = ["foo","bar"]" yqtest.yaml`

After executing the above command the `values.yml` will be changed to:

```
secrets: 
  - foo
  - bar
abc:
  - pqr
psp:
  - jdfhs
```

Now you can declare an empty array in bash script: `insert_array=()` and can use the same combination of awk and sed`(grep -E '\bVE_' $source_file | awk -v RS=[ -v FS=] 'NR>1{print $1}' | sed 's/"//g')` within a for loop to insert elements to the array `insert_array`.

```
#!/bin/bash
    
insert_array=()
for i in $(grep -E '\bKV_' $source_file | awk -v RS=[ -v FS=] 'NR>1{print $1}' | sed 's/"//g')
  do 
    insert_array+=(\"$i\"); insert_array+=(",") 
  done
```

Note that in bash, the array doesn't separate the elements with ","(comma) by default as, like the `list` structure in python, it separates the elements only using a single space character, but yq command doesn't support it.

> Example: list without comma

This is how the output of the array looks:

```
#echo ${insert_array[*]}
foo , bar
```

### list without ","(comma)

```
# yq -i ".secret = [${insert_array[*]}]" destination.yaml 
Error: bad expression, please check expression syntax
```

### list without ","(comma)

```
# yq -i ".secret = ["foo" "bar"]" destination.yaml 
    Error: bad expression, please check expression syntax
```

So I have inserted an  "," as an element here after each element insertion in for loop and deleted the last "," element using `unset insert_array[-1]`

```
for i in $(grep -E '\bKV_' $source_file | awk -v RS=[ -v FS=] 'NR>1{print $1}' | sed 's/"//g')
 do 
   insert_array+=(\"$i\")
   insert_array+=(",") 
 done
```

> Final Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

insert_array=()
for i in $(grep -E '\bKV_' $source_file | awk -v RS=[ -v FS=] 'NR>1{print $1}' | sed 's/"//g')
  do 
    insert_array+=(\"$i\")
    insert_array+=(",")
  done
unset insert_array[-1] 
yq -i ".secret = [${insert_array[*]}]" destination.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the list of filtered words into a temporary file `temp` like this:
- VE_PASS1
- VE_PASS2

And then apply this list to the value of key `secrets` in `values.yaml` using `yq`.

The script/commands would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

source_file=config.yaml
destination_file=values.yaml
temp_file=temp

readarray -t my_array < <(grep -E '\bVE_' $source_file | awk -v RS=[ -v FS=] 'NR>1{print $1}' | sed 's/"//g')

# yq version 4
touch $temp_file
for i in "${my_array[@]}"; do
  printf '\055 %s\n' $i >> $temp_file
done

yq eval '.secrets |= load("temp")' $destination_file --inplace
```

After running the script, `values.yaml` will look like this:

```
secrets: 
  - VE_PASS1
  - VE_PASS2
abc:
  - pqr
psp:
  - jdfhs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your `readarray` + `awk` + `sed` approach to [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) using [`sub`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/string-operators#sub-regex-replacement) as follows:

```bash
yq -i '
  .secrets = (
    load("config.yaml")
    | map(.pass | sub("^.*\[\"(.*)\"\].*$"; "$1"))
  )
' values.yaml
```

Then, `values.yaml` would contain:

```yaml
secrets:
  - VE_PASS1
  - VE_PASS2
abc:
  - pqr
psp:
  - jdfhs
```